# hybris - copy data folder

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

Scenario: Here we have hybris developer who has is local environment set. A new developer on board the team.

1.Place the projects under custom folder
2.ant all
3.can we copy data folder from the developer machine who has the fully loaded database with all necessary data? If yes what needs to be done after copying?

Comment: You can copy data folder from other developer for your internal purpose. You just need to replace other data folder with your one and start the server.

Comment: Thanks Shreshtt. I did. When I tried to do SOLR indexing I get below exception: _de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: When run
ning in embedded mode, a call to getSolrServerMaster can only be made on the mas
ter server_

Comment: Which mode are you using for Solr - Embedded or Standalone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your development environment can be built from script. You do not want to be copying things around randomly.

Check your workspace in to your repository, whatever you are using. Ignore most things, not your custom code obviously.

Use a commonly available location for large resources such as the hybris suite zip.

Have your new developer checkout the workspace and run the script. This should pull in and extract resources, run ant build, build/deploy any other tools or applications in your project.

Do not check in data directories and do not copy these around. You can either:

- use a shared mysql development instance
- init from impex every time and ensure all data is in impex.

I highly recommend your development data can be entirely built out from impex and you can reinit often. This will be needed for development.